# Cо всех input просуммировать значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть неизвестное кол. инпутов с одним классом. Мне надо взять из всех значения и просуммировать и вывести 1 число в конце. 
Как я делал

```
$( ".input_quantity" ).each(function() {

           var arr = new Array();
            arr.push(Number($(this).val()));
            var summ =0;
            for (var i =0; i< arr.length; i++) {               
                summ +=arr[i];
            }
                console.log(summ); 
          });
```

Не выходит суммировать, выводится каждое число и инпутов отдельно. Скорей всего, я метод подсчета выбрал неверный - через ".each". Подскажите другую идею ?

Answer (score 3):

`each`— это цикл. Ты на каждой итерации цикла пытаешься вычислить сумму. И весьма странным способом.

Вынеси объявление суммы до цикла и дальше в цикле складывай:

```
var summ = 0;

$(".input_quantity").each(function() {    
    summ += +$(this).val();            
});

console.log(summ);
```

Comment: Спасибо, свежий взгляд спас!